# Why isn't my progress dialog showing up?

Tags: android, progressdialog, ui-thread

In the code below, I have two fragments that get shown when their respective tabs are selected. Both of these fragments run asynctasks and are supposed to show progress dialogs while they do that. The first fragment (ndi) shows its progress dialog, while the fragment bnf never shows its progress dialog. Why is this? When i click the tab that is case 1 in the switch, the switching of the tabs is very slow when my connection is slow and the screen freezes. I think the ui thread is locked up somewhere but I'm not sure where. Let me know if you need anymore info. Thanks.

```
public class NasaAppActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private Bundle savedInstanceState;
    private static View mainView;
    private FragmentTransaction ft;
    BreakingNewsFragment bnf;
    NasaDailyImage ndi;

    @Override

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart(); 
        if(savedInstanceState==null){
            ndi=new NasaDailyImage(this);
            bnf=new BreakingNewsFragment(this);     
            ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.focused_view_container,ndi).commit();

            getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            ndi.onRefresh();

            ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.focused_view_container,bnf).commit();
                getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

        }
    }

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction f) {

    switch(tab.getPosition()){
    case 0:
        ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.hide(bnf);
            ft.show(ndi);
            ft.commit();
           getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions(); 
        break;
    case 1:
            ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.hide(ndi);
            ft.show(bnf);
            ft.commit();
            bnf.fetchStories(); 
          getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
         break;
    }

}
```

This is the progress dialog that doesn't work and should show up after calling bnf.fetchStories()

```
public class RssNewsParser extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Story>,String,ArrayList<Story>>{
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private BreakingNewsFragment bnf;
    private URL newsURL;
    private ArrayList<Story> stories=new ArrayList<Story>();
    private int eventType;
    private int storyCount= -1;
    private Activity mainActivity;
    private ArrayList<String> storyTitles=new ArrayList<String>();

    RssNewsParser(Activity mainActivity,BreakingNewsFragment bnf){
        this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
        this.bnf=bnf;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Story> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        for(Story story:stories){
            storyTitles.add(story.getTitle());
        }

        bnf.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainActivity,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,storyTitles));
        dialog.hide();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();   
        dialog=ProgressDialog.show(mainActivity, "Loading", "loading news");
    }
```

This is the dialog that does work, I'm baffled because they are used in the same exact way. This one gets shown when ndi.onRefresh() runs its asynctask.

```
public class RssParseSync extends AsyncTask<String,String,Bitmap>{  
        private Context parent;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private static Bitmap final_image; //must be static because a new instance is required to access getFinalImage();
        private String imageURL="";
        private static String imageName;
        private long totalTime;
        private long startTime;
        private static View v;
        private Activity mainActivity;


        public RssParseSync(View v,Activity mainActivity){

            this.v=v;
            this.mainActivity=mainActivity;

            String result=mainActivity.toString();
        }
  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image){

                    ImageView imageView=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(image); 
                    dialog.dismiss(); 
                    //this.cancel(true);
                }

protected void onPreExecute(){
                    if(final_image!=null){
                        final_image.recycle();
                    }

                    nullAllViews();
                    dialog=ProgressDialog.show(mainActivity, "Loading", "Loading the image of the day");
                }



private void nullAllViews(){
                TextView titleView;
                titleView=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
                titleView.setText(null);

                TextView dateView=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageDate);
                dateView.setText(null);

                TextView descriptionView=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageDescription);
                descriptionView.setText(null);

                ImageView imageView=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

            }


package com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class BreakingNewsFragment extends ListFragment {
    private static Activity mainActivity;
    private static ArrayList<Story> stories=new ArrayList<Story>();
    private static ArrayList<String> storyTitles=new ArrayList<String>();

    public BreakingNewsFragment(){

    }
    public BreakingNewsFragment(Activity mainActivity){
        this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);


    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        String url = stories.get(position).getURL();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void fetchStories(){

        RssNewsParser parser=new RssNewsParser(mainActivity,this);
        if(stories.isEmpty()){
        parser.execute();

                try {
                    stories=parser.get();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
            //stories=parser.getStories();


    }
public void updateList(){
    //String result;
    //result = storyTitles.toString();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainActivity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,storyTitles));
}
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();




    }
    public void onRefresh() {
        fetchStories();

    }

}
```

Comment: what is in your `nullAllViews()` ?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem lies in `BreakingNewsFragment`. Can you post code for that, specifically anything that would get called when creating and resuming the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `parser.get()` forces your code to wait for the `RssNewsParser` task to complete. By doing this you are effectively pausing the main thread of your application for the length of your `fetchStories` operation. In other words, you are defeating the purpose of using an `AsyncTask`.

As a suggestion, you should probably using `Loaders` instead of `AsyncTasks` to get your RSS information back to your activity / fragment.  They essentially do the same thing, but Loaders will help you keep your RSS information between rotates and it will be easier to get the result back to your activity and views.

Answer (score 0):

fetchStories() are executing in the main thread, that is causing all the problems, hangs/Progress dialog not visible.

Comment: Can you give me some more details? Why does my other task run fine? Am I just calling the task in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong way of using `AsyncTask`. And why you keep calling 'executePendingTransaction()'? Whats the hurry? Anyway after analyzing your code I suggest removing following code:

```
 try {
                stories=parser.get();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Please understand the working of 'AsyncTask'. You must wait for it to finish and do whatever you want to do in `onPostExecute()`. After calling 'execute()' its a mistake to fetch data manually on next line.

Comment: @dymmeh Above answer suggests moving from `AsyncTask` to `Loaders` whereas I suggested correct usage of `AsyncTask`, asking him to wait till `onPostExecute()` is called.